# Securit risks of serializing from PHP to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection, full-text-search

I'm serialising PHP arrays for storage in a MySQL TEXT field (as you do), and I'm wondering if I need to take any precautions regarding injection attacks (do I need to base64 encode it, for example). Also, can anyone offer a good way of storing an array in a MySQL DB so that a FULLTEXT search will work on it reasonably well? Serialized data might work ok-ish, but it might not. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks,

James

Comment: Injection is easily avoided by escaping, which one should do anyway with _every_ data one sends to MySQL, just to be 100% sure (or, stored procs). It costs very little CPU and adds has very little storage overhead. However, apart from injections, one non-obvious security risk might be, in case that data is confidential, if you encrypt it in MySQL (e.g. aes_encrypt). Even if you communicate with the server via SSL, your data may possibly be compromised, because MySQL will write it to the journal in plaintext. So, to be 100% safe, encrypt on your end, don't trust the SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a parameterized query, where you separate your actual SQL code from the content, you do not need to worry about injection.

The default in PHP, as you seem to use, would be using PDO. CHeck the manual [pdo::prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)